# Geometric calculations in a django model

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I'm working on a Django web project. I have a model called Ad. I need to add coordinates to each Ad object and then query the database by the distance from a fixed point, i.e. retrieve all Ad objects within the distance of 5 km from a fixed point. I've read about GeoDjango, but I'm a little bit confused.

I have a large postgresql database of regular django models, and I'm not sure how I can combine my current database with a spatial database. Even if I can create a spatial database and use two databases for my project, I won't be able to reference a model from my regular database I suppose. What can I do in this case? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a standard PostgreSQL database into a spatial database (i.e. a PostGIS database).  You will need to:

1. [Build/install PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ch02.html).
2. Add the spatial data types and functions to your existing database.  See the section [Create a spatially-enabled database](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ch02.html#id2619431) in the PostGIS documentation.
3. Once you have added the spatial functionality, you should be able to [add geometric fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/) to your models.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [GeoDjango](http://geodjango.org/). It uses PostGIS as geospatial DB so you will not need to set up additional DB.

Comment: I tried but I can not add geometric fields to my models. Do I need to change my database backend to support spatial data, or connect to the same database with another backend?

Answer (score 0):

other answers mention postgis.  for completeness i will also mention pgsphere.  http://pgsphere.projects.postgresql.org/

the difference between the two is that pgsphere is for points on a "theoretical" sphere, while postgis is intended for points on the surface of the earth.  that may sound odd - it basically means that postgis includes support for particular map projections, while pgsphere is just about basic spherical trignometry.

i mention phsphere because if you are happy with the maths / approximations involved then it is, in my experience, simpler and easier to install and use.  on the other hand, if you don't know how to convert from the angular distance between two points to their actual distance, or you need to accurately handle coordinates in a particular map projection, then postgis is preferable.  the integration of postgis with geodjango, which ilvar mentions, may also be a point in postgis's favor in your case.

either way, you need to compile the package, then enable and extend your database, as tyler describes.